# How can I observe a game in Company of Heroes?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I'd like to view online multiplayer games, but I did not find a way to observe games. Is that possible, and if so, how?

(I already know the answer and am going to post it if noone replies within a few days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a spectator mode built into the game, but the mod Operation Market Garden does include a spectator mode.

[Operation Market Garden game modes (including spectator mode)](http://www.omgmod.org/wiki/index.php/Game_Mode)